# Using CASE to Update a table, receiving a weird error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I have two queries I'm currently using to Update tables in my DB, both use CASE. This is my first time actually using CASE.

The first query works swimmingly, without a hitch:

```
SET ct1name = CASE
             WHEN xd_id <= '200' THEN 'test'
             END
```

However, my second query does not, it returns an error:

Error it produced

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'trxstate', table 'eqcas.dbo.cat_transaction'; column does not
>   allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The statement has been terminated.

This is the query:

```
USE eqcas
UPDATE cat_transaction 
SET trxstate = CASE WHEN trxtype = 'pho' AND
                         trxsubtype = 'cal' AND
                         trxstate='2' AND
                         trxdate <= '2015-11-30 23:59:59'
                    THEN '1' 
               END
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong as I can't see where I've indicated that null should be input in that column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not specify an `ELSE` in your `CASE` expression, it will default to `NULL`.

Your `UPDATE` statement updates all rows in `cat_transaction`. And since you do not have an `ELSE` part, those who fail the condition are assigned a value of `NULL` which then produces the error.

You should put the condition in the `WHERE` clause instead.

```
UPDATE cat_transaction 
    SET trxstate =  '1'
WHERE
    trxtype = 'pho' 
    AND trxsubtype = 'cal' 
    AND trxstate = '2'
    AND trxdate <= '2015-11-30 23:59:59'
```

This way only the rows that satisfy the condition get updated.

Comment: Actually, that's better then our answers... +1.

Comment: Thanks to ALL! Thanks to you @Felix Pamittan!

Comment: @Stunt Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should really read the error message. It's there to help you understand what went wrong. In this case, it's because you are updating a null value into a column that does not allow nulls.

the fact that your `CASE` statement doesn't have an `ELSE` clause means that it will return `NULL` when the condition evaluates to false. 
so you need to add an `ELSE` to that statement. something like this should do the trick:

```
UPDATE cat_transaction 
SET trxstate = CASE WHEN trxtype = 'pho' 
                    AND trxsubtype = 'cal' 
                    AND trxstate='2' 
                    AND  trxdate <= '2015-11-30 23:59:59' 
               THEN '1' 
               ELSE trxstate 
               END
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have an `ELSE` condition, the value to be inserted will default to `NULL` if the case condition be false.  To correct this, you can add a value for `ELSE` which is not `NULL`:

```
UPDATE cat_transaction 
SET trxstate = CASE WHEN trxtype = 'pho' AND
                         trxsubtype = 'cal' AND
                         trxstate='2' AND
                         trxdate <= '2015-11-30 23:59:59'
               THEN '1' 
                   ELSE ''
               END
```

If you don't want to add the `ELSE` condition, then the alternative would be to make the `trxstate` column nullable (which it currently is not).